# How to prove that this polynomial is larger than another for positive reals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $a, b$ and $c$ be positive real numbers. Prove that
>   $$a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a + ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2 \ge 6abc$$

I have tried factoring with no success for the better part of an hour or so.  How can I go about this?

Comment: Do you know the AMGM inequality?

Comment: I do not know of it, but I am looking at it on Google and im not sure how to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AM-GM inequality:
$$
\frac{a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a + ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2}{6} \ge \sqrt[6]{a^2 b \cdot b^2 c \cdot c^2 a \cdot ab^2 \cdot bc^2 \cdot ca^2}=abc,
$$
with equality iff $a=b=c$.

Ps. Also directly with Muirhead [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality) since your LHS is $\sum_{sym}a^2b$, RHS is $\sum_{sym}abc$ and $(2,1,0)>(1,1,1)$